# Error trying to serve user uploaded files locally

Tags: django, django-urls, django-staticfiles, django-file-upload

I'm trying to serve user-uploaded images locally on Django 1.10. I'm following [the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) and getting this error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
Your URL pattern [<RegexURLPattern None ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$>] is invalid. 
Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
```

The issue is from adding the `static` portion of my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...my urls...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    # This is causing the error.
    urlpatterns += [
        static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    ]
```

When I remove the `static` addition to my urls, the error goes away. What am I doing wrong here?

My applicable settings are as follows:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + "/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + "/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that `static` should not be inside a list. This line:

```
urlpatterns += [
    static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
]
```

should be:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```